# Flutter AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper Error

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-test

I do not think that I have changed anything, and I have reverted any changes, but still my app has stopped working in the IOS simulator. I have tried all sorts of things, but for some reason I get this massive error.

Flutter clean does not work. Re-installing Xcode does not work. Updating the IOS target deployment doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
     Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        objc[79923]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffc39eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103cb44f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
        objc[79923]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffc39f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103cb4548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
        objc[79923]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffc39f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103cb4598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
        objc[79923]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffc39fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103cb45e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
        objc[79923]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffc39ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103cb4638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
        objc[79923]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ffc3a040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103cb4688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
        2022-04-30 23:35:18.327 xcodebuild[79923:184898] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
        2022-04-30 23:35:18.328 xcodebuild[79923:184898] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
        --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D679F6E4-2715-4144-A5CA-1C7B57E32F7B, OS:15.4, name:iPad (9th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3ED5629B-C700-4246-ACA8-6FC7E73EE2D1, OS:15.4, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DD511D60-C5E5-4F6F-A433-AA77C942C424, OS:15.4, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FDB29FAA-2A70-4B42-85ED-7428C2ED26BF, OS:15.4, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E9343349-B165-4E00-80E9-169670981DC7, OS:15.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D3623A79-7380-46ED-8CB7-651559E6876E, OS:15.4, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:52F2A081-F7EF-4130-8EF4-9233AD2ECE45, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 8 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:31E45369-D605-4F9D-A093-057113A6B7B4, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1C06D49F-547B-4361-93C7-E01713AB56A9, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 11 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:60195D52-01B9-437B-AB49-5E12E7C7C092, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F16D84C5-3E7E-459C-9D47-194D6E25EF42, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:758B40D3-F2A8-4C95-B1A9-A16B19261F23, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 12 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1EB0FCE1-576F-4A62-BDC6-DD0C94F0988B, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3831DEF5-288C-4128-A070-706E828EDEB4, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7AAA7C57-23BE-46BB-892E-78EE6F23B868, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 12 mini }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F4F11D4C-538D-4B4A-80CF-4676EFC93BDE, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 13 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:680CA2DD-47D2-43D8-8DD3-0AF6FBFB9815, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D5B8FDDD-34CF-4E25-9BE4-0D2D63E96A90, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7C058821-BDC9-4C84-A621-057CA56589B6, OS:15.4, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7CE00049-D147-4340-B0DB-E6578E58B52F, OS:15.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B1577C3C-0651-421F-B93F-049AB8D8445D, OS:15.4, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-0018645C0CE2001E }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/hermanpalmgren/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.10/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:153:57: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                                           .keyWindow.rootViewController];
                                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/hermanpalmgren/Developer/wondersagas/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/url_launcher/url_launcher-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));
                                                      ^
    1 warning generated.
/Users/hermanpalmgren/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audio_service-0.18.1/ios/Classes/AudioServicePlugin.m:213:59: warning: 'initWithImage:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use -initWithBoundsSize:requestHandler: [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                        artwork = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: artImage];
                                                              ^
In module 'MediaPlayer' imported from /Users/hermanpalmgren/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audio_service-0.18.1/ios/Classes/AudioServicePlugin.m:3:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/Headers/MPMediaItem.h:248:1: note: 'initWithImage:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image MP_DEPRECATED("Use -initWithBoundsSize:requestHandler:", ios(5.0, 10.0));
    ^
```

Answer (score -2):

Using terminal enter

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

Or set command line tools using Xcode preferences.